# hover effect works very briefly on page load but crashes

Tags: css, hover, background-image

I'm having some trouble with the hover effect. I'm trying to change the background image of a div on hover, but it only works when you hover over that image on page load, and as soon as you move the mouse at all I lose the effect.

I can't tell if the problem is in the css or in the script. I've tried removing all of the scripting and still could not get the desired effect. The background image divs are contained by a couple other divs.

I've uploaded the page to http://www.coyotebyrd.com/ourwork.html if anyone would like to see what I'm talking about. The code looks like this:

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("body").css("display", "none");
        $("body").fadeIn(1000);
});

    $(document).ready(function(){
$('a').each(function(index) {
    if(this.href.trim() == window.location)
        $(this).addClass("selected");
});

   $(document).ready(function () {
$("#top").delay(0000).show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 800);
});

   $(document).ready(function () {
$("#bottom").delay(0000).show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 800);
});

   $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#topContainer").css("display", "none");
        $("#topContainer").delay(800).fadeIn(500);
});

   $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#bottomContainer").css("display", "none");
        $("#bottomContainer").delay(800).fadeIn(500);
});

});
```

```
    <div id="top">

    <div id="topContainer">

        <div id="webDesign"><a href="webdesign.html" alt="Responsive Web Design" class="webLink"></a></div>
        <div id="photography"><a href="photography.html" alt="Commercial Photography" class="photoLink"></a></div>

    </div> 

    </div>   

#webDesign {width: 50%;
            height: 100%;
            background-image: url(../Images/Undrst8edDesktopScreen.jpg);
            background-size: cover;
            background-position: center-top;
            float: left;
            display: block;

}

#photography { width: 50%;
           height: 100%;
           background-image: url(../Images/commercialPhotographyBW.jpg);
           background-size: cover;
           background-position: center-bottom;
           float: right;
           display: block;

 } 

#webDesign:hover {
                background-image:url(../Images/Undrst8edDesktopScreenColor.jpg);
                display: block;


}

#photography:hover { 
           background-image: url(../Images/commercialPhotographyColor.jpg);
           display: block;


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay.
The reason why this dosen't work is because of the body property.
Even though body's display set as "None" This still exist in the webpage, and interrupting :hover event.
So, What you have to do is Set a Z-index of Body.

```
body {
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you everyone! I've got it working now. Ecstatic that I signed up for this site and people are so willing to help.

Answer (score 0):

I found your error. This worked for me. In your `<section id="workPage">` position is set to relative. `position: relative`. If you set your position one of this you will get trouble. `absolute` `inherit` `relative` `sticky`.

If you set your position to one of `!important` `fixed` `initial` `static` or `unset` will work hover effect. Try following code.

```
#workPage {
  position: unset;
}
```

Or

you can do this changing your `z-index`. Your current z-index is set to -1 `z-index: -1` in `<section id="workPage">`. Change it to positive value. Ex:

```
#workPage {
 z-index: 1;
}
```